# loading bitmap to array

Tags: memory

I need a bitmap ARRAY ready to be used dynamically.
what i did is.

on Activity i put

```
public static Bitmap[] bitmapArray;

bitmapArray = new Bitmap[10];
```

then to use with a timer i do

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    BufferedOutputStream out = null;

    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(),
                IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

        final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
        copy(in, out);
        out.flush();

        final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        // options.outHeight=50;
        // options.outWidth=50;
        // options.inScaled=true; //inSampleSize = 1;
        // options.inSampleSize=3;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,
                options);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeStream(in);
        closeStream(out);
    }

    return bitmap;
}



for i.........
MyActivity.bitmapArray[i]= loadBitmap( url........
```

And this is the problem. if i have on the heap a block of 10 (Bitmap[10])
bitmaps buffers i want it to stay fix!!Same memory location.
but each timer iteration the program load the buffer to a DIFFERENT block location
which very soon the memory is finished.
any idea?
P.S i need the above solution fixed since i need the bitmap buffer to be used fast.

Comment: There is very little information here. Method signatures, and class descriptions would be very helpful.

Comment: You don't even tell us what language you're using, or where/how these classes are defined.

Comment: Sorry it is Android java using Eclips for debugger.Each iteration i see a diffrent bitmap location. for example bitmapArray[1] is at a different location then the next iteration of the timer . p.s the timer is in a service. dose it make a difference?

Comment: Java tends to allocate arrays upon image reads. Are you sure allocation and gc are your bottlenecks?

Comment: Yes - this is the only function in the timer. It loads 10 jpg to buffer > a must for speed. After a while it fails on memory too big. Checking on the debugger on second iteration you see the address of bmp[i] has changed. The heap grows. I am porting a Delphi app to Android so java is not my main language.

Comment: I imagine that the array is allocated on get image so the question how to allocate a  fix position bmp array. to write always on the same position?